# each / respectively

Tags: grammar

I have 3 cases.

> Case 1. Some of the mice were injected with A, some with B, and some
>   with C.

Which expression(s) would be correct, which would be most precise, or any other answers?

a) 5cc of each of A, B, and C were obtained and injected into the mice.
b) 5cc each of A, B, and C were injected into the mice.
c) 5cc of each of A, B or C was injected into a mouse of this study.
d) 5cc of each of A, B, and C were obtained and injected into the mice, respectively.
e) 5cc each of A, B, and C were injected into the mice, respectively.

> Case 2. There were three mice. First mouse was injected with A, second
>   with B, and third with C.

Which expression(s) would be correct, which would be most precise, or any other answeres?

a) 5cc of each of A, B, and C were obtained and injected into the mice.
b) 5cc each of A, B, and C were injected into the mice.
c) 5cc of each of A, B or C was injected into a mouse of this study.
d) 5cc of each of A, B, and C were obtained and injected into the mice, respectively.
e) 5cc each of A, B, and C were injected into the mice, respectively.

> Case 3.  Each mouse was injected with 5cc each of A, B, and C.

a) 5cc of each of A, B, and C were obtained and injected into the mice.
b) 5cc each of A, B, and C were injected into the mice.
c) 5cc of each of A, B or C was injected into a mouse of this study.
d) 5cc of each of A, B, and C were obtained and injected into the mice, respectively.
e) 5cc each of A, B, and C were injected into the mice, respectively.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

- "Injected to the X" isn't a correct usage of "inject," it cannot be
  used with a "to the..." prepositional phrase, because you can't
  "inject to" something. You can use "into" instead.
- Although "5cc" is written without an "s" because we don't pluralize units of measurement in writing, it is still understood to be plural, so "was" should also be "were."
- "Or" is the logical counterpart to "and." "A, B, or C" means one of the three. "A, B, and C" means *all* of the three. Don't confuse them.
- "5cc of each of..." is redundant. You can use "5cc each of..."
- "Into each mouse" and "into the mice" are virtually the same in this context.
- "Respectively" is also redundant. You use the word "respectively" to show a relation between two lists of things. For instance, if I had three different flavors of ice cream, and three different children, I could say that "Jonny, Sarah and Kyle each received strawberry, chocolate and vanilla, respectively." This means that Jonny received strawberry, Sarah received chocolate, and Kyle received vanilla. "Respectively" means that the items relate to each other in the same order you list them. Since there is only one list of things -- the different medicines -- and you don't list out the individual mice, it's not applicable here.

Here is the most correct version of your sentence by my reckoning:

> 5cc each of A, B, and C were obtained and injected into each mouse.

or

> 5cc each of A, B, and C were obtained and injected into the mice.

Comment: I don't think the abbreviations of units of measure typically use plural inflections.

Comment: Actually, you're right, when it comes to writing -- I had forgotten that for just a second. However, the subject is still understood to be plural, so "were" is still necessary. Not to mention there are multiple kinds of medicine being injected.

Comment: Yes I completely agree.